How do suggestions for modules work in Jupyter Notebook for VS Code?
I'm trying to use typical libraries such as matplotlib, numpy or scipy for scientific work. When I type, for example np., I sometimes get a list with available functions, and, for instantiated classes, a list of methods. Just like in  How to Prioritize Python Module Suggestions in VS Code?
However, at other times, without doing anything differently, no suggestions appear, nor the arguments of the functions. What's more, while I can import modules, I get the opposite message: Import "numpy" could not be resolvedPylancereportMissingImports
I don't really understand what is going on. I would like to know how these suggestions work, and how they are toggled on or off.

First, make sure you are using good vs code extensions.If that is good then setup the proper virtualenv for that. Hope this helps!.

I don't know what extensions I'm using, and I'm not using a virtual environment either. I don't think it's worth it for a generic Matlab-like use.

did you select a kernel yet? does that kernel have the module you want installed yet?

Yes, I have all the modules installed via pip. The kernel is the generic Python.

According to the document about jupyter in vscode.
You have to choose your python interpreter first.
To select an environment, use the Python: Select Interpreter command from the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P).
Then choose your jupyter kernel in the upper right corner.
